# Get Facebook Messenger to update message text

Tags: javascript, facebook, eventtrigger, facebook-messenger

So I'm coding a javascript script that can swap your text with other text. For example, if I type ---, the script would swap the hyphens with an em dash. This works well, except with facebook messenger. The issue is, when my script changes the innerHTML of the span that holds the text, it doesn't update the text on their server.

If you reload messenger, it remembers your text. If you reload messenger right after the script made a swap, it remembers the text pre-swap. However, if the script makes a swap, and then the user continues typing, the messenger remembers the text with the swap.

I suspect that when the user types, it triggers an event that messenger uses to save the current contents of the message.

What I'm looking for is a method to trigger this event, or to get messenger to save the current contents straight from the javascript.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I can clarify!

For clarification, check out my video explanation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4xepgi524XzOUo4bW5KaVJmZHc/view

Comment: You should add some code into your question and maybe even some pictures

Comment: @Quill, added a video explanation